# How can I change the font size of form values using php?

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to change the font size of a form output. The user should be choosing the font size from radio buttons and I have 4 options for it (15px, 20px, 24px and 30px). I applied the necessary CSS in the style section. I gave different IDs to each checkbox. How can I change the size of the output using PHP?[The "Course Name" at the bottom of the screen should change font size after submiting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8VNp.png)

Comment: you mean randomly on the html page and while the user is looking at his page?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: no. First, the user is going to choose what they want to print from the dropdown list, and then secondly, they are going to choose the font size, which will print the option they chose from the list and the font size.

Comment: You can't do that with only  PHP code running on a server for dynamic acting on a browser client, you need to use javascript coding

Comment: Your are going to need to post a small example of what you are trying to do

Comment: right sorry, guys, I'm new. I posted a picture. I hope that helps

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

it would be easy if you use a select input

i belive that you have on page for the form that the user choose these and other that you process the information.

page one (form)
you will need to add som javascript so the user will only select one option

```
  <form method="post">
    <input type='checkbox' class='conf-1' data-conf='1' value='15' name='option15' >
    <input type='checkbox' class='conf-1' data-conf='1' value='20' name='option20' >
    <input type='checkbox' class='conf-1' data-conf='1' value='24' name='option24' >
    <input type='checkbox' class='conf-1' data-conf='1' value='30' name='option30' >

    <input type="submit" value="save!"/>
  </form>

<script>
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
        // in the handler, 'this' refers to the box clicked on
        var box = $(this);
        var idCheck = box.data('conf');
        var group = "conf-"+idCheck;

        if (box.is(":checked")) {
            // the name of the box is retrieved using the .attr() method
            // as it is assumed and expected to be immutable
            // the checked state of the group/box on the other hand will change
            // and the current value is retrieved using .prop() method
            $("."+group).prop("checked", false);
            box.prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            box.prop("checked", false);
        }
        
    });
</script>
```

page two (process information)

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")  {
   if(isset($_POST['option15']))){
        $sizeOption= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['option15']);
   }
   if(isset($_POST['option20']))){
        $sizeOption= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['option20']);
   }
   if(isset($_POST['option24']))){
        $sizeOption= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['option24']);
   }
   if(isset($_POST['option30']))){
        $sizeOption= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['option30']);
   }

//now you can use the var $sizeOption

}
```